# 'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, in rhapsody

Tags: rhapsody

I tried VSIBM® Rational® Rhapsody® 8.2.1, C. And it does not recognize 'nmake'.
That's the message I got:

> Executing: ""C:\raf\Share"\etc\msvcmake.bat msbuild.mak build x86 VC11
>   "LIB_PREFIX=MSVC11x86$(MT_PREFIX)" "USE_PDB=FALSE" "BUILD_SET=Debug" 
>   " The system cannot find the path specified. 'nmake' is not recognized
>   as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> Build Done

tnx

Answer (score 1):

Does C:\raf\Share\etc\msvcmake.bat contains the path to VS 2012?
It should look like:

if "%4"=="VC11" set VS_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\